Archive events through flows
I have a requirement where I need to delete current event records and have them archived. For this I have created a new custom object to store the event details called 'Archived Event'.
The flow works correctly for the most part except creating the new archived event records. But it deletes the existing event record.
My Flow:

Temp variable to store archived event record details:

Archived event collection variable

Assigning values to temp record variable:

Adding it to Collection variable:

Creating records by passing the collection variable:

It seems very straight forward but it's not creating the new archived event records. Any suggestions?

Have you tried debugging the flow? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_flow_debugging_sbu

maybe your loop is never executing because it is looping over the wrong record collection variable.  Flow debugging will help pinpoint the cause

Yes, I have debugged the flow. But apparently the problem lies with WhatId field. I'm using WhatId field to filter out and retrieve the event records. This is not possible based what I found.
